# Difficulty in saving separate figures matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I have written a program in python to map the random positions of points on a disc for a project. The idea is that for different numbers of points the random positions will be saved as a png for use later. The code is as follows:

```
def randr():#random r position
  return random.random()

def randphi():#random phi position
  return 2*pi*random.random()

nrange=[3,10,11,12,15,20,25,30]

for N in nrange:
   rposition=[]#create a table of r positions
   phiposition=[]#create a table of phi positions
   rinverse=[]#create a table of 1/rij

   for listcreation in range(0,N,1):#go through each charge
      rposition.append(randr())#allocate a random r position
      phiposition.append(randphi())#allocate a random phi position

   name=N
   filename = "c:/users/V/%i.png" % name
   pyplot.polar(phiposition,rposition,marker='o', markersize=10,color='b',
             linestyle='none')
   pyplot.savefig(filename, format='png')
```

The problem is that when this code is run the first figure saves with 3 points but the second one saves with 13 instead of 10! This goes on for successive N

I cannot post images so you'll have to take my word for it or run the code.

Does anyone know how to overcome this?

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your post so it's clear what is inside what.

Comment: is this more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the axes are not cleared between plots, so when you plot the second plot, it adds to whatever was already plotted.  To clear it, insert `pyplot.cla()` before your `polar` call.

Answer (score 0):

I have found in similar situation it is good to properly initialise an axis that is

```
for N in nrange:
    {Make the data}

    ax = py.subplot(111)
    ax.plot({data})
    py.savefig...
```

This will automatically clear the axis and is clearly readable. If you also use `py.xlabel` you may wish to change these to `ax.set_xlabel` instead to make it clear.